# cannot import name 'InceptionV3' from 'keras.applications' How to fix?

Tags: python, tensorflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPDHz.png)

How to fix ?  I Not think fix it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I think you are importing `InceptionV3` from `keras.applications`.

You should try something like

`from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3`

it will solve the problem